# How to write a simple test for a Snack Bar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, snackbar

I'm surprised no one seems to have asked this before, which means the answer might be obvious, but I have  a screen with a text field and a button. The user enters their email in the text field. Then presses the button to see if the email is in the database. The program then displays a snackbar with 'success' text or 'fail' text (2 second duration).

Here is my code (5 lines):

```
await driver.enterText(field, 'wrongemail@email.com');

var btn = find.widgetWithText(RaisedButton, 'SEND MY PASSWORD');

await driver.tap(btn);

await driver.pump();

expect(find.text( 'E-mail address not found!'), findsOneWidget);
```

When I use the app in the emulator, everything is fine but in the test the last line throws an error saying that it cannot find the matching widget.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 7):

Have you wrapped your test widget in a Scaffold? SnackBars can only be shown if a Scaffold is an ancestor of the widget that calls the SnackBar.

Example:

```dart
void main() {
  testWidgets('SnackBar control test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    const String helloSnackBar = 'Hello SnackBar';
    const Key tapTarget = Key('tap-target');
    await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                  content: Text(helloSnackBar),
                  duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                ));
              },
              behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
              child: Container(
                height: 100.0,
                width: 100.0,
                key: tapTarget,
              ),
            );
          }
        ),
      ),
    ));
    expect(find.text(helloSnackBar), findsNothing);
    await tester.tap(find.byKey(tapTarget));
    expect(find.text(helloSnackBar), findsNothing);
    await tester.pump(); // schedule animation
    expect(find.text(helloSnackBar), findsOneWidget);
  });
```

From: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/test/material/snack_bar_test.dart

Comment: Yes, your answear is working, thanks

Comment: now Snackbar usage is: `ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(`.

Answer (score 0):

Without the entire code it is a bit difficult to give a definite answer, but I will try an "educated guess". The problem lies most likely in not providing a duration for driver.pump(). As a result the test will advance just a frame and then check that the SnackBar is visible. If after pressing the button your program does some useful work (such as checking if the email address is present in the database) that will take probably longer than one frame.

Basically your test is doing the check too early, before your code has the chance to display the SnackBar.
Calling pump with a duration of 1 or 1.5 seconds should give the program enough time to display the SnackBar.